# How do I load a service worker before all other requests?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to load a service worker before all subresource requests on the page so I can apply some optimizations to the way subresources are loaded (e.g. lazy-loading, loading minified versions of assets instead of full assets). However, I cannot find a way load my SW before other subresource requests begin.

I created a simple proof-of-concept of what I'm trying to do to 401 any requests handled by my Service Worker (just to make it easier to find when my SW begins handling requests).

Here's my HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <script>
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('/dl-wps-sw.js', { scope: '/' }).then(function (registration) {
                console.log('Service Worker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
            }, function (err) {
                console.error(err);
            });
        }
    </script>
    ...
```

and here's my Service Worker:

```js
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('activate', () => {
    self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    const init = {status: 401, statusText: 'Blocked!'};
    event.respondWith(new Response(null, init));
});
```

This is what happens in my browser:
[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, even though my code to register the Service Worker is at the very top of the page, it doesn't activate and begin handling requests until a bit later, and by then a large number of critical requests I need to catch have already fired.

I found someone else who seemed to be trying to do what I'm trying to accomplish (2 years earlier) in a Github issue for the Service Worker spec: https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1282

It seems they suggested using a `<link rel="serviceworker"...` tag to do this, but it appears this link type has since been removed from Chrome for some reason: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5682681044008960

I've tried several other ideas to attempt to load my SW first:

- Preloading my SW with a `<link rel="preload"...` tag
- Preloading my SW with a `fetch`/`XMLHttpRequest`
- Inlining the Service Worker in the HTML (not possible apparently)
- Delaying the execution of the page by running a while loop for a few seconds (this kinda worked, but its a terrible unpredictable hack)

Any ideas or strategies I'm missing? My Google-fu has failed me on coming up with a solution.

Comment: I recommend you to use Workbox, and avoid using "navigator.serviceWorker.registe" all the time, first check if any worker are registered yet.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on Workbox. Unfortunately, I don't think it will help with this specific issue. I don't see anything in it that addresses this initial load start time dilemma. Perhaps I'm wrong, so please let me know if so.

Comment: @jameslk does below's answer suffice? still need help? I can try

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to install the SW alone first, then refresh the page.  The SW can then serve content for a SW-enabled page and intercept all other requests.  Example: [fetch-progress.anthum.com](https://fetch-progress.anthum.com/sw-basic/)

**index.html**

```
<p>Installing Service Worker, please wait...</p>

<script>
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
  .then(reg => {
    if (reg.installing) {
      const sw = reg.installing || reg.waiting;
      sw.onstatechange = function() {
        if (sw.state === 'installed') {
          // SW installed.  Refresh page so SW can respond with SW-enabled page.
          window.location.reload();
        }
      };
    } else if (reg.active) {
      // something's not right or SW is bypassed.  previously-installed SW should have redirected this request to different page
      handleError(new Error('Service Worker is installed and not redirecting.'))
    }
  })
  .catch(handleError)

  function handleError(error) {}
</script>
```

**sw.js**

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  const url = event.request.url;
  const scope = self.registration.scope;

  // serve index.html with service-worker-enabled page
  if (url === scope || url === scope+'index.html') {
    const newUrl = scope+'index-sw-enabled.html';
    event.respondWith(fetch(newUrl))
  } else {
    // process other files here
  }
});
```

**index-sw-enabled.html**

```
<!-- 
  This page shows after SW installs.
  Put your main app content on this page.
-->
```

Comment: I think this is a solution that accurately answers my question. I was hoping to find a solution that wouldn't slow down the initial page load for first time visitors (this would due to the refresh), but I'm guessing this is simply not possible right now with limitations in Service Workers. I've accepted the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Great point.  You could potentially mitigate that using the [app shell pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/App_structure#App_shell) and caching `index-sw-enabled.html` during SW's `oninstall` event.

Comment: Can I use the example code in my own commercial project or do some license restrictions apply?

Comment: Yes, I believe you can. Technically, Stackoverflow may own it https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service

Answer (score 2):

While the default behaviour for a new service worker is to wait until the next page load to take over from the previous one, a service worker can in fact begin controlling existing pages immediately using the `Clients.claim()` method.

So, by including something like this in your service worker, you should be able to avoid the need to refresh:

```
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  event.waitUntil(clients.claim());
});

self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  self.skipWaiting();
});
```

You can read more about `Clients.claim()` [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/claim).